# Can you use a styled-component keyframe inline on a component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm attempting to create a twinkling star effect in my app. I have created an array and looped through it to get the number of "star" `div`s, and I used styled components to style the stars. I'm attempting to animate them each randomly, but in order to do that I have to randomize the properties in-line when the divs are being created while looping. Attempting to get random values in the styled-component gives the same value to each div. My code is currently as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes, css } from 'styled-components'
import styles from './Stars.module.scss'

const flicker = keyframes`
    0%,100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

`
const Star = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: white;
`
const StarContainer = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
`

const vpHeight = window.innerHeight;
const vpWidth = window.innerWidth;

const starCount = () => {
    const count = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= 300; i++){
        count.push(i)
    }
    return count
}

const Stars = () => {
    return (
        <StarContainer id='star-container'>
            {starCount().map((star, i) => (
                <Star style={{
                    animation: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)}s ${flicker} infinite`,
                    top: `${Math.floor(Math.random()*vpHeight)}px`,
                    left: `${Math.floor(Math.random()*vpWidth)}px`
                }} />
            ))}
        </StarContainer>
    );
}

export default Stars;
```

However this gives the following error: `Error: It seems you are interpolating a keyframe declaration (gvlTRP) into an untagged string. This was supported in styled-components v3, but is not longer supported in v4 as keyframes are now injected on-demand. Please wrap your string in the css\\ helper which ensures the styles are injected correctly. See https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css`

I'm not sure how to proceed. Is there a way to include the `styled-component` keyframe in the inline element styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to keep the keyframes static, and then do something like this:

```
// keep the keyframes declaration static
const flicker = keyframes`
  /* etc. */
`;

const Star = styled.div`
  animation: ${flicker} infinite;
  animation-duration: ${props => props.animationDuration};
`;

// later...

<Star animationDuration={Math.random() * 8} />
```

Comment: That works perfectly as expected! I'm still not too sure what the issue with my code was however, would you be willing to explain that for me?

Comment: @JoshBangle The issue is that Styled Components keyframes don't play nicely with React's `style` prop; React expects an object, with each property being a CSS property with a clean string value, whereby `keyframes` actually generates some sort of internal Styled Components object. When you interpolate `flicker` inside of your `styled.div` declaration, Styled Components picks up on that and then converts it into some sort of animation declaration, but React cannot do the same.